# i am not able get kannada text from .html file while i am running the program from browser

Tags: perl

i am having a perl program that get corpus from web using the wget command of shell,but while using lynx -dump command to extract data from html but this is working fine from the command prompt but when i am tying to run the same program form browser the kannada text from the files is not extracting from files i am able to get only the english text my program is like this

in `$f.txt` files i am only able to get english text while i am running perl program in browser but `my $f` having kannada text too. so please do help me

```
foreach my $f(@files)
system("lynx -dump $f > $f.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a block (curly braces) with a `for` statement (for and foreach are aliases):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $f (@files) {
    system("lynx -dump $f > $f.txt");
}
```

You should also make a habit out of always using `use strict; use warnings;`. It may seem easier to code without them, but it is just an illusion.